# Delete Google+ cover photo

Tags: google-plus

How do I delete or change a cover photo? Every guide I find is at least two years old and NONE OF IT is relevant to the new business listings in Google+.

https://plus.google.com/+BarrJonesAssociatesLLPColumbus/posts?hl=en

Not the user photo/icon—that's a piece of cake to update. I'm trying to change the big cover photo that looks like it came from 1996. I did not set this page up originally, but the admin account was handed to me, so I have full access. I deleted every photo in the admin account at https://plus.google.com/photos. These images also do not exist anywhere in the "manage" section of the business listing. There's no edit or remove button hovering over the image while logged in as the admin. They do appear in the album "Scrapbook photos" when viewing the Google+ page above, but this album does not appear to be editable.

Comment: If you are using Google Talk,then the picture you are setting would be taken as the cover photo of the Google + account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When viewing the page the bottom right of the cover image has a "change cover" button when you hover the mouse over the image.

[image]